# Inject component tag dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have multiple drop divs and so every time i drop the image of a component into those div i import the component corresponding to this image and i need to put it into the dom in the target div

```
drops[i].addEventListener('drop', function () {
    if (this.draggedElement === null) {
        return false
    }

    // get the component conf of this image
    let conf = BlocksStore.conf[this.draggedElement.dataset.category].blocks[this.draggedElement.dataset.type]

    // get the component itself (./blocks/SimpleTitle.vue)
    let component = require('./blocks/' + conf.component)

    drops[i].classList.remove('drag-enter')

    // here is where i don't know what to do ...
    drops[i].innerHTML = component
    this.draggedElement = null
}.bind(this))
```

Here the code of ./blocks/SimpleTitle.vue

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <a href="#" title="Lorem Ipsum" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px !important; color: #010101;">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'simple-title'
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I already tried to append the tag instead of the component but the dom don't comprehend it as a component

Comment: What does your `"/blocks/" +conf.component` file export? Sharing its code would surely help.

Comment: Take a look to an example of drag and drop image, maybe it could be helpful to fix your problem https://codepen.io/raffo1234/pen/bZQXwZ

Comment: Thanks @ricardoorellana but the problem is not with an image but with a component. The image is just a placeholder of the component until the user drops it

Comment: This is a job for [Dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

Comment: I can't use dynamic components because i don't know where the component will be since i allow the user to drag and drop the component everywhere he wants